# My iOS release rejected by App Store cause by launch crash, how to solve it?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, app-store, flutter-dependencies

We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Review device details:

- Device type: iPhone and iPad
- OS version: iOS 16.6

Rejection Reasons:

2.1.0 Performance: App Completeness

Rejection Attachments:
crashlog-745C64F7-913A-45EB-B962-A350EA6A8498.txt

```
{"app_name":"Runner","timestamp":"2023-08-03 11:06:03.00 -0700","app_version":"4.0","slice_uuid":"b64b5af1-6517-363f-b657-2520698f25dd","adam_id":"6453696580","build_version":"2","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.smartbooking.mpklang","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 16.6 (20G75)","roots_installed":0,"name":"Runner","incident_id":"745C64F7-913A-45EB-B962-A350EA6A8498"}
{
  "uptime" : 270000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPhone14,4",
  "coalitionID" : 2023,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 16.6",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "20G75"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-08-03 11:06:02.4745 -0700",
  "incident" : "745C64F7-913A-45EB-B962-A350EA6A8498",
  "pid" : 10777,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2023-08-03 11:06:02.4150 -0700",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 6536078491998,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 6536079847514,
  "procName" : "Runner",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Runner",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"4.0","CFBundleVersion":"2","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.smartbooking.mpklang","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"14E221"},
  "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"6453696580","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"EC1D6236-7615-4F07-84DD-D31BD5D41791","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"858770353"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.smartbooking.mpklang",
  "crashReporterKey" : "37417fec9fc51c7c4fb51a3ea29ac626f07cbbd1",
  "wasUnlockedSinceBoot" : 1,
  "isLocked" : 0,
  "codeSigningID" : "com.smartbooking.mpklang",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "3S2L25DLAC",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570450689,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 4,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 0,
  "basebandVersion" : "2.80.01",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "termination" : {"code":1,"flags":518,"namespace":"DYLD","indicator":"Library missing","details":["(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)"],"reasons":["Library not loaded: @rpath\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter","Referenced from: <B64B5AF1-6517-363F-B657-2520698F25DD> \/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/Runner.app\/Runner","Reason: tried: '\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/priva"]},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":1745672,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6},{"value":1},{"value":6103935952},{"value":151},{"value":6103934928},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":32},{"value":9},{"value":1},{"value":10},{"value":0},{"value":49},{"value":4},{"value":32768},{"value":521},{"value":7791760568,"symbolLocation":416,"symbol":"__simple_bprintf"},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6103934928},{"value":151},{"value":6103935952},{"value":1},{"value":6},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":6103938464},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":7791815448},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":6103934880},"sp":{"value":6103934816},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7791771596,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":8737056944}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":446412,"symbol":"__abort_with_payload","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":490264,"symbol":"abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":490316,"symbol":"abort_with_payload","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":106500,"symbol":"dyld4::halt(char const*)","symbolLocation":328,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":99084,"symbol":"dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)","symbolLocation":4124,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":89308,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":1948,"imageIndex":4}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4362944512,
    "size" : 6258688,
    "uuid" : "b64b5af1-6517-363f-b657-2520698f25dd",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Runner",
    "name" : "Runner"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4373381120,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "fce25557-2265-3ff5-8e53-36cf17d310c6",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/flutter_webview_plugin.framework\/flutter_webview_plugin",
    "name" : "flutter_webview_plugin"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4373512192,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "7d889dd0-46eb-360a-86c1-ebb1d6ad4db3",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/path_provider_foundation.framework\/path_provider_foundation",
    "name" : "path_provider_foundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4373643264,
    "size" : 32768,
    "uuid" : "bec3a9f7-2f11-3860-9923-75cb4101d6a9",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/url_launcher_ios.framework\/url_launcher_ios",
    "name" : "url_launcher_ios"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7791325184,
    "size" : 547412,
    "uuid" : "c3fc2ee4-367f-3086-beb8-420ad442bf88",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 7147732992,
  "size" : 3017703424,
  "uuid" : "a2436193-29a3-3d6a-93ea-6704ae3e774d"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=326.6M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=326.6M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=2416K written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=2416K(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nSTACK GUARD                         16K        1 \nStack                             1008K        1 \nVM_ALLOCATE                         16K        1 \n__DATA                            1860K        6 \n__DATA_CONST                        18K        1 \n__DATA_DIRTY                        12K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       320.0M        5 \n__TEXT                            6776K        7 \ndyld private memory               1296K        2 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                            330.7M       25 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {

  }
},
  "logWritingSignature" : "ef2d4d8ceb8c45fc67213e6a102d185d56c66f16",
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "62c74108bcb0435c2153f963",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "64ac900a4cd4605149f19654"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000283
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "62699e1ec1ff2978b47f6c3b",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_FIND_MY_CONFIGURATION_FILES" : "631f72d1de559130376df1fb"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000023
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [
    {
      "treatmentId" : "679e587d-a834-415a-8277-5f4e57a44e92",
      "experimentId" : "64a6ffb205dfd5094f195306",
      "deploymentId" : 400000007
    },
    {
      "treatmentId" : "32e33d73-ae56-4dd2-9f32-a064e9db0b31",
      "experimentId" : "62e47e747613a16313832faa",
      "deploymentId" : 400000033
    }
  ]
}
}
```

crashlog-55E4D60A-B3F5-4AE5-9462-24A5CCB584FC.txt

```
{"app_name":"Runner","timestamp":"2023-08-03 11:06:04.00 -0700","app_version":"4.0","slice_uuid":"b64b5af1-6517-363f-b657-2520698f25dd","adam_id":"6453696580","build_version":"2","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.smartbooking.mpklang","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 16.6 (20G75)","roots_installed":0,"name":"Runner","incident_id":"55E4D60A-B3F5-4AE5-9462-24A5CCB584FC"}
{
  "uptime" : 270000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPhone14,4",
  "coalitionID" : 2023,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 16.6",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "20G75"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-08-03 11:06:04.2453 -0700",
  "incident" : "55E4D60A-B3F5-4AE5-9462-24A5CCB584FC",
  "pid" : 10778,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2023-08-03 11:06:04.2399 -0700",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 6536122291570,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 6536122414709,
  "procName" : "Runner",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Runner",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"4.0","CFBundleVersion":"2","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.smartbooking.mpklang","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"14E221"},
  "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"6453696580","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"EC1D6236-7615-4F07-84DD-D31BD5D41791","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"858770353"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.smartbooking.mpklang",
  "crashReporterKey" : "37417fec9fc51c7c4fb51a3ea29ac626f07cbbd1",
  "wasUnlockedSinceBoot" : 1,
  "isLocked" : 0,
  "codeSigningID" : "com.smartbooking.mpklang",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "3S2L25DLAC",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570450689,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 4,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 0,
  "basebandVersion" : "2.80.01",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "termination" : {"code":1,"flags":518,"namespace":"DYLD","indicator":"Library missing","details":["(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)"],"reasons":["Library not loaded: @rpath\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter","Referenced from: <B64B5AF1-6517-363F-B657-2520698F25DD> \/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/Runner.app\/Runner","Reason: tried: '\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/priva"]},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":1745697,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6},{"value":1},{"value":6167522256},{"value":151},{"value":6167521232},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":32},{"value":9},{"value":1},{"value":10},{"value":0},{"value":49},{"value":4},{"value":32768},{"value":521},{"value":7791760568,"symbolLocation":416,"symbol":"__simple_bprintf"},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6167521232},{"value":151},{"value":6167522256},{"value":1},{"value":6},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":6167524768},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":7791815448},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":6167521184},"sp":{"value":6167521120},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7791771596,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":8737056944}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":446412,"symbol":"__abort_with_payload","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":490264,"symbol":"abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":490316,"symbol":"abort_with_payload","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":106500,"symbol":"dyld4::halt(char const*)","symbolLocation":328,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":99084,"symbol":"dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)","symbolLocation":4124,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":89308,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":1948,"imageIndex":4}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4299358208,
    "size" : 6258688,
    "uuid" : "b64b5af1-6517-363f-b657-2520698f25dd",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Runner",
    "name" : "Runner"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4309794816,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "fce25557-2265-3ff5-8e53-36cf17d310c6",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/flutter_webview_plugin.framework\/flutter_webview_plugin",
    "name" : "flutter_webview_plugin"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4309925888,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "7d889dd0-46eb-360a-86c1-ebb1d6ad4db3",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/path_provider_foundation.framework\/path_provider_foundation",
    "name" : "path_provider_foundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4310056960,
    "size" : 32768,
    "uuid" : "bec3a9f7-2f11-3860-9923-75cb4101d6a9",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/url_launcher_ios.framework\/url_launcher_ios",
    "name" : "url_launcher_ios"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7791325184,
    "size" : 547412,
    "uuid" : "c3fc2ee4-367f-3086-beb8-420ad442bf88",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 7147732992,
  "size" : 3017703424,
  "uuid" : "a2436193-29a3-3d6a-93ea-6704ae3e774d"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=326.6M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=326.6M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=2416K written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=2416K(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nSTACK GUARD                         16K        1 \nStack                             1008K        1 \nVM_ALLOCATE                         16K        1 \n__DATA                            1860K        6 \n__DATA_CONST                        18K        1 \n__DATA_DIRTY                        12K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       320.0M        5 \n__TEXT                            6776K        7 \ndyld private memory               1296K        2 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                            330.7M       25 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {

  }
},
  "logWritingSignature" : "ef2d4d8ceb8c45fc67213e6a102d185d56c66f16",
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "62c74108bcb0435c2153f963",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "64ac900a4cd4605149f19654"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000283
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "62699e1ec1ff2978b47f6c3b",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_FIND_MY_CONFIGURATION_FILES" : "631f72d1de559130376df1fb"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000023
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [
    {
      "treatmentId" : "679e587d-a834-415a-8277-5f4e57a44e92",
      "experimentId" : "64a6ffb205dfd5094f195306",
      "deploymentId" : 400000007
    },
    {
      "treatmentId" : "32e33d73-ae56-4dd2-9f32-a064e9db0b31",
      "experimentId" : "62e47e747613a16313832faa",
      "deploymentId" : 400000033
    }
  ]
}
}
```

crashlog-1D9E716C-2D21-4189-A5B8-E98E9AE83518.txt

```
{"app_name":"Runner","timestamp":"2023-08-03 11:06:04.00 -0700","app_version":"4.0","slice_uuid":"b64b5af1-6517-363f-b657-2520698f25dd","adam_id":"6453696580","build_version":"2","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.smartbooking.mpklang","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 16.6 (20G75)","roots_installed":0,"name":"Runner","incident_id":"1D9E716C-2D21-4189-A5B8-E98E9AE83518"}
{
  "uptime" : 270000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPhone14,4",
  "coalitionID" : 2023,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 16.6",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "20G75"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-08-03 11:06:04.2574 -0700",
  "incident" : "1D9E716C-2D21-4189-A5B8-E98E9AE83518",
  "pid" : 10779,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2023-08-03 11:06:04.2531 -0700",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 6536122607873,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 6536122703480,
  "procName" : "Runner",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Runner",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"4.0","CFBundleVersion":"2","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.smartbooking.mpklang","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"14E221"},
  "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"6453696580","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"EC1D6236-7615-4F07-84DD-D31BD5D41791","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"858770353"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.smartbooking.mpklang",
  "crashReporterKey" : "37417fec9fc51c7c4fb51a3ea29ac626f07cbbd1",
  "wasUnlockedSinceBoot" : 1,
  "isLocked" : 0,
  "codeSigningID" : "com.smartbooking.mpklang",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "3S2L25DLAC",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570450689,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 4,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 0,
  "basebandVersion" : "2.80.01",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "termination" : {"code":1,"flags":518,"namespace":"DYLD","indicator":"Library missing","details":["(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)"],"reasons":["Library not loaded: @rpath\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter","Referenced from: <B64B5AF1-6517-363F-B657-2520698F25DD> \/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/Runner.app\/Runner","Reason: tried: '\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Flutter.framework\/Flutter' (no such file), '\/priva"]},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":1745700,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6},{"value":1},{"value":6169193424},{"value":151},{"value":6169192400},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":32},{"value":9},{"value":1},{"value":10},{"value":0},{"value":49},{"value":4},{"value":32768},{"value":521},{"value":7791760568,"symbolLocation":416,"symbol":"__simple_bprintf"},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6169192400},{"value":151},{"value":6169193424},{"value":1},{"value":6},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":6169195936},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":7791815448},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":6169192352},"sp":{"value":6169192288},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7791771596,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":8737056944}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":446412,"symbol":"__abort_with_payload","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":490264,"symbol":"abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":490316,"symbol":"abort_with_payload","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":106500,"symbol":"dyld4::halt(char const*)","symbolLocation":328,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":99084,"symbol":"dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)","symbolLocation":4124,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":89308,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":1948,"imageIndex":4}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4297687040,
    "size" : 6258688,
    "uuid" : "b64b5af1-6517-363f-b657-2520698f25dd",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Runner",
    "name" : "Runner"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4308123648,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "fce25557-2265-3ff5-8e53-36cf17d310c6",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/flutter_webview_plugin.framework\/flutter_webview_plugin",
    "name" : "flutter_webview_plugin"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4308254720,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "7d889dd0-46eb-360a-86c1-ebb1d6ad4db3",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/path_provider_foundation.framework\/path_provider_foundation",
    "name" : "path_provider_foundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4308385792,
    "size" : 32768,
    "uuid" : "bec3a9f7-2f11-3860-9923-75cb4101d6a9",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/DDC74BF7-F8C3-4C7A-89F6-4D4CC0727D8C\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/url_launcher_ios.framework\/url_launcher_ios",
    "name" : "url_launcher_ios"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7791325184,
    "size" : 547412,
    "uuid" : "c3fc2ee4-367f-3086-beb8-420ad442bf88",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 7147732992,
  "size" : 3017703424,
  "uuid" : "a2436193-29a3-3d6a-93ea-6704ae3e774d"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=326.6M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=326.6M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=2416K written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=2416K(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nSTACK GUARD                         16K        1 \nStack                             1008K        1 \nVM_ALLOCATE                         16K        1 \n__DATA                            1860K        6 \n__DATA_CONST                        18K        1 \n__DATA_DIRTY                        12K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       320.0M        5 \n__TEXT                            6776K        7 \ndyld private memory               1296K        2 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                            330.7M       25 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {

  }
},
  "logWritingSignature" : "ef2d4d8ceb8c45fc67213e6a102d185d56c66f16",
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "62c74108bcb0435c2153f963",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "64ac900a4cd4605149f19654"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000283
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "62699e1ec1ff2978b47f6c3b",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_FIND_MY_CONFIGURATION_FILES" : "631f72d1de559130376df1fb"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000023
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [
    {
      "treatmentId" : "679e587d-a834-415a-8277-5f4e57a44e92",
      "experimentId" : "64a6ffb205dfd5094f195306",
      "deploymentId" : 400000007
    },
    {
      "treatmentId" : "32e33d73-ae56-4dd2-9f32-a064e9db0b31",
      "experimentId" : "62e47e747613a16313832faa",
      "deploymentId" : 400000033
    }
  ]
}
}
```

I try to search website and try solve but didn't solve it, I think the problem is about flutter.framework not loaded

When I try on my real device its only work on when connecting to Xcode but when stop the Xcode the app will crash and go back will launch crash

After that in Xcode has error about the dependencies file `'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found`

Comment: You should ensure that the Flutter.framework library is properly included in your app's bundle and that it is correctly referenced.
Use the flutter pub get command to ensure that all required packages are installed

Comment: these links maybe help you:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48035 ,
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49504#issuecomment-581554697

Comment: flutter pub get runs already is same

Comment: for the link its call me downgrade iOS version of real device, maybe I can downgrade mine but how come I call App Store downgrade its iOS version